# MeteorJS: How to get value of an input text

Tags: javascript, node.js, meteor, coffeescript, pug

I have this code:

*product.jade*

```
template(name="product")
    label(for="qty") Qty:
    input#qty.form-control(type="text", value="1", name="qty")
    button.btn.btn-default.addcart Add to Cart
```

*product.coffee*

```
Template['product'].events
  'click .addcart': (event, template) ->
    ????
```

How do I get the value of input text `qty`? I tried the event variable but its limited in the button. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Considering your code you can get the value like this:

```
'click .addcart': (event, template) ->
    qty = template.find('#qty').value;
```

You can see here the documentation about [`template.find()`](http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/template_find).

But if you have a submit event on your `<form>` you can also do this:

```
'submit .your-form': (event, template) -> 
    qty = event.target.qty.value //qty = name of the field
```